# Change the effects of :hover when user scrolls #px using jquery

Tags: jquery

I hope some of you can help me out with this.

I am making a single page website, which includes some jquery. The navigation bar is fixed to the top of the page and starts as 100px in height.

The jquery I have used so far includes;

1. Scroll animation so when a navigation link is click to scroll the user to the relevant section of the page. I have not included this jquery code in this question.
2. When scrollTop reaches 650px, the navigation bar re-sizes to 50px in height and the width of the containing row (which includes the links) is reduced to 900px (from 1280px).

You can see this scrollTop jquery from my JSFiddle, or code below - http://jsfiddle.net/josh_boothman/QvME2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var scrollTop = 650;
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= scrollTop){
            $('.row').css({
                width: '900px',
                margin : '0 auto'
            });

            $('#header').css({
                height: '50px'
            });
        }

        if($(window).scrollTop() < scrollTop){
        $('.row, #header').removeAttr('style'); 
        }
    });
```

});

What I would also like to achieve is: when the user scrolls to the various sections on the page, the :hover effect on the navigation links changes i.e. to a different color.

So I would like something along the lines of:

When user has scrolled 1200px then the nav link hover changes from blue to red, as an example.

Is there any way that this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance. Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better achieved by using a CSS:

```
#header[data-section=start]:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#header[data-section=about]:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#header[data-section=last]:hover {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Then, on your js, toggle the `data-section` attribute according to where the user is in the page:

```
var sections = {
  'start': { start: 0,   end: 400  },
  'about': { start: 400, end: 1000 },
  // ...
  'last':  { start: 1000 },
};

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var $window   = $(this);
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

  var section;
  Object.keys(sections).forEach(function(name) {
    var bounds = sections[name];

    if(bounds.start < scrollTop && (bounds.end > scrollTop || !bounds.end)) {
      section = name;
    }
  });

  $("#header").attr("data-section", section);
});
```

If you put the attribute on the `body` instead (and using selectors of the type `body[data-section=start] #header:hover`), you can extend this technique to do pretty much any effects you want using only with CSS (transitions, animations etc).

Example: http://jsbin.com/riwofisa/1/edit (scroll, then hover the topbar)

---

To accommodate your current code to this format, you may want to use the technique I mentioned above, by changing the last line of the script I posted from:

```
$("#header").attr("data-section", section);
```

To:

```
$("body").attr("data-section", section);
```

Then, on the CSS:

```css
/* Changing the color of hovered links */

body[data-section=start] #header a:hover {
  color: lightgreen;
}

body[data-section=about] #header a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

body[data-section=last] #header a:hover {
  color: lightblue;
}

/* The changes you previously made via JS */
body[data-section=last] #header {
  height: 50px;
}

body[data-section=last] .row {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Of course, after adjusting the section names/boundaries to your needs.

Example: http://jsbin.com/riwofisa/2/edit?css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for that. I've had a look at your example and it seems to be very similar to what I would like to achieve.

Presumably, a bit of tweaking would allow me to target a navigation link as opposed to the whole #header in this case?

Also, would this fit into my existing jquery or would I add it after what I already have?

Comment: Glad it helped! Let me know if you think there's anything missing from the answer

Comment: Sure, you can use selectors like `#header[data-section=home] a:hover` to change only the links. And as your current code, you can achieve what you were doing by passing the css changes to the css itself. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I've updated the answer. AFAICS, this is enough to substitute the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this Renato. I've tweaked it ever so slightly to accommodate my needs and it works just as I wanted. I'm very grateful. One thing I have noticed though (although I have resolved it) - When I set my start points i.e. 700 (the 2nd <section> it didn't change the color, until I scrolled ever so slightly. I solved this by making the start point 2 less i.e.. 698. It's not an issue and solved the problem. I was curious if you would know why. All my padding etc is reset to 0.

Comment: Glad to hear! No, I'm not sure why this would happen